# getting Nashorn null error while running karate tests

Tags: karate

I am running karate tests where my karate version is 0.9.5
and java is

```
    java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_275-b01)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.275-b01, mixed 
    mode)
```

I am getting Nashorn Null error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke “javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()” because “com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN” is null
```

What could be the possible reason for it. Tried on 1.8.0_275 version as well

Comment: it works well on version 1.8.0_222

Comment: @PeterThomas my jdk version is greater than 1.8.0_111 and still getting error. Can you please recheck the question

Comment: it works for me. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue or better still start planning to use the version that will be released soon and does not have the nashorn error: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide